# Как добавить микроразметку к сайту на Laravel

Tags: laravel, seo, laravel-5.7, микроразметка

Подскажите, может кто сталкивался, как можно добавить к сайту на Larvel микроразметку ? Может есть какой-то пакет , который можно загрузить и прост в настройке?

**Буду очень благодарен! Спасибо**

Comment: каждый проект на любом фреймворке индивидуален и разметка его тоже индивидуальна. Это не Wordpress c его публичными темами и плагинами.
Микроразетку надо делать вручную. Это касается как логики формирования микроразметки, так и размещения ее в шаблонах. **Другого пути нет**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В случае в `фреймворками`, у Вас не получится найти что-то похожее. Это не `CMS` (`WordPress` или `Битрикс`). Для `CMS` создана целая куча плагинов, позволяющих вмешиваться в вывод `HTML` в виду того, что у них всё фиксировано. Но у каждого проекта на базе фреймворка может быть разная `HTML-структура` страницы. Это что-то вроде самописного сайта.

Вот пример структуры шаблона одного из проектов:

```
<ul class="breadcrumb" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/BreadcrumbList">
    <li itemprop="itemListElement" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ListItem">
        <a class="home" href="/" itemprop="item">
            <span itemprop="name">Home</span>
        </a>
        <meta itemprop="position" content="1">
    </li>
    <li itemprop="itemListElement" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ListItem">
        <a href="/catalog" itemprop="item">
            <span itemprop="name">Catalog</span>
        </a>
        <meta itemprop="position" content="2">
    </li>
    <li class="active" itemprop="itemListElement" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ListItem">
        <span itemprop="item">
            <span itemprop="name">Computers</span>
        </span>
        <meta itemprop="position" content="3">
    </li>
</ul>
```

У Вас может быть также, а может и по-другому.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ!

Comment: Пожалуйста. Пользуйтесь.